# The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or ... http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

The code used to work fine (Outlook addin - a number of years back) however I am now seeing the following ;

"The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

on the following;

```
http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/id/{00062008-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}/8514000B
```

I have also tried a few other similar links seen in other similar code examples around and they too are returning the same message.

As I cannot seem to find any info on this in hunting, appreciate of someone knows more and could enlighten me. 
Cheers.

Comment: Maybe the add-in is not working due to some other issue - this is a red herring (?) as Dmitry said, it is not a URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a url, it is a DASL property name.